# mount an mdadm raid 1 drive at boot

Tags: 14.04, server, raid, fstab, automount

I was wondering if you guys could help. I am looking to mount my mdadm RAID 1 at boot.

The drive location is `/dev/md127` and I would like it to mount to `/media/server` at boot. It is formatted to `ext4`. Your help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could add an entry to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/md127    /media/server    ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Make sure that `/media/server` is present:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/server
```

You could use the `UUID` of the partition instead of `/dev/md127`. The UUID of a filesystem is unlikely to change unless you alter it, whereas the partition may change its identifier and be named md0 or md255 or something like that.

Use the `blkid` or `lbslk` command to get the UUID, and then replace `/dev/md127` with `UUID=xxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxx` in the above line:

```
# lsblk -o NAME,UUID
NAME    UUID
sdc     
└─sdc1  8ebc357c-3d93-fd86-0535-cb852bbc7289
  └─md2 5348f582-8a9c-43c3-bf5b-eaabd644035b
sdd     
└─sdd1  8ebc357c-3d93-fd86-0535-cb852bbc7289
  └─md2 5348f582-8a9c-43c3-bf5b-eaabd644035b
# blkid
/dev/sdc1: UUID="8ebc357c-3d93-fd86-0535-cb852bbc7289" UUID_SUB="77e19cfe-ed79-613f-bb18-b56bc30e0858" LABEL="titan:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="8ebc357c-3d93-fd86-0535-cb852bbc7289" UUID_SUB="e99d0a33-4944-4f1e-4a90-b65fa2e57b56" LABEL="titan:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/md2: UUID="5348f582-8a9c-43c3-bf5b-eaabd644035b" TYPE="ext4"
```

The UUID of `/dev/md2` (the RAID array in this case) is `5348f582-8a9c-43c3-bf5b-eaabd644035b`, so the entry would look like:

```
UUID=5348f582-8a9c-43c3-bf5b-eaabd644035b   /media/server   ext4    defaults  0 0
```

Comment: I will give that a shot, what would be the difference or advantage of using the UUID rather than the /dev/md127 ?

Comment: The UUID of a filesystem is unlikely to change unless you alter it, whereas the partition may change its identifier and be named `md0` or `md255` or something like that.

Comment: that seems like a better option to use the UUID. What is the command for me to obtain the UUID of a madam raid

Comment: @Chris Use `sudo blkid`, or `sudo lsblk -o NAME,UUID`.