# Moved main HD and 2 RAID1 Drives into new computer... created problems!

Tags: hard-drive, raid, mdadm

First off, I'm really not great at code or anything, I honestly fumbled my way through this original Ubuntu build.

I've got an Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS setup, originally I was using an old HP 6005 SFF (mind you the system was running fine here) but a friend gave me a slightly better (still old) computer HP Z230 workstation, so I thought I'd be able to just pop my hard drives out of the old system and into the new and see what happens...which worked...sorta.

The system has 3 hard drives:
Main drive for the OS/apps - everything booted fine here, everything boots good/loads OS no problem.
2 x 3TB WD Red Pro drives that were setup in RAID1 before - used to show as a single "md0" in old system, now these show as 2 separate drives (sdb1 and sdc1) and I can't seem to open/access files because of this.

Question is, how do I re-setup the RAID1 with these 2 drives in Ubuntu and NOT lose any data? These have all of my movies, music, files, family pictures on them (mirrored of course).
I did make sure RAID emulation is enabled in BIOS, so that’s good.

Everything was orinally setup in the Linux software RAID with mdadm.
I figured I'd just be able to tell the system that these 2 drives "sdb" and "sdc" are in the db0 RAID1 setup...but I guess that's harder than I thought! Or maybe not?

**Any help is appreciated, thank you!**

I tried:

'cat /proc/mdstat' comes back with:
Personalities: [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] ...
unused devices:

Comment: How **exactly** did you set up the RAID in the past?  You aren't using RAID1 on your primary system as a substitute for proper backups, are you?

Comment: I honestly don’t recall how I’d setup the RAID1 config originally, I do know it was the software route using Mdadm. I’m not sure what you mean about using the RAID1 as a proper backup? I basically use the 2 drives as mirrors of each other (RAID1)...they both have all my Movies, Music...etc on there. They don’t backup my main hard drive that runs the OS, if that’s what you’re asking.

Comment: I'm asking if you can restore from actual backups? Search for: "RAID is not a Backup". RAID1 is great for additional redundancy *on the disks where you keep your backups*, but using RAID1 *instead* of backups is not good for protecting your data.  Since everything is mirrored to the other drive, it offers no protection from corruption and human error... RAID protects against one and only one thing: Drive failure...  Have you seen this topic on mounting mdadm RAID on boot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/540202/mount-an-mdadm-raid-1-drive-at-boot?r=SearchResults